# How to find only matching nodes (specific information) in one to many relation record in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

How to show only the highlighted record in MongoDB. When I set the filter as shown in the image to show only ENAME = 'MARCO', it shows all nodes as E1,E2,E3,E4,E5.

Hope somebody can answer my query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D found this answer:

db.Multisql.aggregate([{$unwind: "$Customers"}, {$match: {"Customers.FIRST_NAME": "TEST"}}])